# How can i build a graph in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, graph

How can I build a graph in Haskell having :

```
type Node = Int
type Arc = (Node, Node)
```

and the function:

```
class Graph g where
         build :: [Node] -> [Arc] -> g
```

Comment: `Graph` is not a type, it's a type class. You need to define a suitable type first.

Answer (score 9):

Currently you just a have a [typeclass](http://learnyouahaskell.com/types-and-typeclasses#typeclasses-101), which is sorta like an OOP interface. Just like an interface, you can't actually "construct" a class. You need to select a concrete implementation (using the keyword `data`) and then implement the function `build` on it. This is what you'd then pass around to functions that want a `Graph`

For a simple example:

```
--The concrete data type
data NaiveGraph = NG [Node] [Arc]

--Now we make it an instance of Graph
instance Graph NaiveGraph where
   build = NG
```

This may or may not be an acceptable instance depending on what you want to do. More information on your actual goals would help me suggest a better representation.